# Can we use AUTHID CURRENT_USER in triggers?

Tags: oracle

I have created a trigger as follows to create a table whenever a new row inserted in the table all_tables_used.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_table
AFTER INSERT ON all_tables_used
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE '||:new.table_name||'('||:new.column_name||')';
   execute immediate v_sql;
END;
```

While inserting data in the table all_tables_used it is throwing 'ORA-01031: insufficient privileges' error.

Can we use AUTHID CURRENT_USER in triggers to resolve this issue?

Comment: Creating a table is DDL which issues an implicit commit, so you can't do that from a trigger anyway. But why would you want to? Creating a table (or any object) isn't something you should be doing at runtime, never mind from a trigger.

Comment: We can use PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to avoid the issue of implicit commit.

Comment: Yes, but I'd consider that abusing rather than using that feature. You're trying to do somethiing  that suggests your data model is wrong.